# Why is it that $x=\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric

I'm supposed to find the curve of intersection of $z=x^2-y^2$ and $x^2+y^2=1$. I usually go about this by parametrization. I set $x=t$ and plug and chug the other variables. However that won't work easily in this situation.

My instructor recommended I use $x=\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$ instead. I'm curious as to how and why this will work, since I know that my method of parametrization doesn't change the values of the original variables, but this one seems to.

So why does using $x=\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$ work?

Comment: $x=\cos t, y=\sin t$ is a parametrization of the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$: every point $(x,y)$ on this circle can be written as $(\cos t,\sin t)$ for some $t\in\left[0,2\pi\right)$

Comment: @A.Goodier What does that E mean? I've heard of this, but what if $t$ exceeds $2pi$?

Comment: $\in$ means belongs to. So I'm saying we can restrict to $0\leq t<2\pi$. If $t$ is outside this range, we still get a point on the unit circle, but restricting to $\left[0,2\pi\right)$ just generates the circle once, so it suffices to only consider  values of $t$ between $0$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: @A.Goodier Can I use this form of parametrization even when I'm not dealing with circles. And I don't quite understand what happens when I'm outside of $2pi$. Does it mean, we just get another circle, rotation per se?

Comment: No, you can only use this parametrization for this particular circle $x^2+y^2=1$. Beyond $2\pi$, you will go round the same circle again.

Comment: @A.Goodier Why only this circle though? Why can't I apply in linear functions? And why can I use it here since it's a hyperbola?

Comment: Because it's the parametrization of this circle. Other curves have different parametrizations.

Comment: You can substitute it into $z=x^2-y^2$ here because you are trying to find where $z=x^2-y^2$ meets $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: Ok, last question. What if the radius was not $1$, what if the radius was $2$ instead. Would it just be, $x=2 cos(t)$?

Comment: Yes, for a circle of radius $2$ centred at $(0,0)$, $x=2\cos t, y=2\sin t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set *x = cos(t)* and *y = sin(t)*, then the equality *x$^2$ + y$^2$ = 1* is always fulfilled, due to the Pythagorean identity *sin$^2$(x) + cos$^2$(x) = 1*. Therefore, since the second equation is always true given the circumstances, you can simply plug in the values of *x* and *y* into the first equation and that will give you your desired curve, which in this case is *z = x$^2$ - y$^2$*, or *z = cos$^2$(t) - sin$^2$(t)* or, according to the double angle formula: *z = cos(2t)*

Comment: Good start (+1). It may be beneficial to emphasize that this recipe gives us ALL the solutions to $x^2+y^2=1$. And exactly once when we restrict $t$ to a half-open interval of length $2\pi$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Congrats on the first upvotes :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Can I use this parametrization on other functions or do they have to be a circle? And why does it work when one of the functions is a hyperbola.

Comment: @Asker123 An equation like $x^2+y^2=r^2$ screams to be parametrized as $x=r\cos t$, $y=r\sin t$ - a standard trick :-). On a hyperbola $x^2-y^2=r^2$ I would use $x=r\cosh t$, $y=\sinh t$.

Answer (score 1):

This is literally the definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$. The $\sin$ of a number $t$ is the $y$-coordinate of a point $t$ radians along the unit circle, measured in a counterclockwise direction from $(1,0)$. The $\cos$ of $t$ is that same point's $x$-coordinate. Thus, as $t$ increases from $0$, the point $(\cos t,\sin t)$ simply tracks motion around the circle, *by definition*.

You may have seen $\sin$ and $\cos$ defined some other way, perhaps in the context of right triangles? Showing that the two definitions are equivalent is a good exercise. These functions can also be defined other ways, such as in terms of certain differential equations. The unit circle definition is a good one, though, for many purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trig identity you may recall, $cos^{2}\theta + \sin^{2}\theta=1$. This answers your direct question since you can match up $x^2 + y^2 =1$